# Visualizer for WPF elements

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, debuggervisualizer

Trying to create visualizers for some WPF elements including `DrawingImage` and `UIElement` etc. While [creating a visualizer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164759.aspx) was trivial, my visualizers always throw exception that the target object types (`DrawingImage` and `UIElement` that is) are **not marked as serializable**.

Further reading revealed that I need to implement `VisualizerObjectSource` to provide custom serialization. This class is specified as one of the arguments in `DebuggerVisualizer` attribute. I followed these steps and now my custom serializer gets called, but I don't really know what to do in there. Here is the relevant function that gets called:

```
public override void GetData(object target, Stream outgoingData)
{
  var writer = new StreamWriter(outgoingData);
  writer.WriteLine(/*???*/);
  writer.Flush();
}
```

Don't understand exactly what it is expecting from me (a binary-serialized version of the `UIElement`?) and exactly how do I write a `UIElement` or a `DrawingImage` to the outgoing stream. Anyone has done this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally managed my way through it. It is much simpler than I had thought. For anyone else trying to find their way, here is how it works:

Firstly, `GetData()` override (read the question) is to be managed by YOU. You have to decide what you want to send in to the visualizer. Send in enough information so that you're able to construct the object back in the `Show()` call.

For WPF elements, serialization proved to be FAR simpler than what I was thinking. There are built-in `XamlReader` and `XamlWriter` classes that you can use to perform serialization/deserialization of WPF objects.

Once you have reconstructed the object in `Show()`, it is simply a matter of showing it in a `Form`. Note that Visual Studio supports old-school `Form` and `Control` classes only (WinForms that is), not WPF `Window`s, but you can workaround this issue by placing an `ElementHost` in your form or control and then assigning reconstructed WPF object as the child of this `ElementHost`.

You may want to add a `ViewBox` layer in between your `ElementHost` and the reconstructed object to fit it elegantly in the available space.

I have uploaded the [WPFVisualizers project on GitHub](https://github.com/Shujee/WPFVisualizers.git) in case anyone is interested. Currently it contains two visualizers, for `DrawingImage` and `UIElement` types. Together these cover most of the visual elements of WPF world, but you're free to add more types in case you need some. The project contains `VisualizerBase` class that contains all the visualizer serialization/communication logic. This makes creating new WPF visualizers as simple as writing 1 line of code, like this:

```
public class GeometryDrawingVisualizer : VisualizerBase<GeometryDrawing, GeometryDrawingControl>
{
}
```

That's it. You have created a new visualizer for `GeometryDrawing` type. The second generic parameter (`GeometryDrawingControl` in the above example) is the WinForms `Control` (or `Form` if you wish) that will constitute the UI of your visualizer. Place an `ElementHost` in your control and then put in whatever your type needs to render.

Comment: Looks promising. BTW nice one.

Comment: You can create a WPF UI for the visualizer, as described [here](https://wrightfully.com/debugger-visualizer-with-wpf), and as is done in [this sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/blob/master/SqliteVisualizer/SqliteVisualizer/VisualizerWindowViewModel.cs#L283).